# Can I assigning specific ports to my android emulators

Tags: android, visual-studio

I have been looking into this, but I cannot seem to find a solution that helps.
I am using the Android Device Manager through Visual Studios 2019. I have installed 3 different android versions, and I would like to use each one through another application. At current, I have to open them each in order, so they are connected correctly through the set ports. Is there away I can assign each port to each emulator, so they use exactly the same port each time that particular emulator is run?

Example: If I run emulator Android version 10 first, it will be as port 5554, then if I run Android version 11, it will be as port 5556. But if I close all down and then run Android version 11, it will be as port 5554.

Can I assign port 5554 to Android version 10, so it always uses that port only and the same with Android version 11, can I assign it to always use 5556?

Many thanks